# floating elements and using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a grid of logo's, 5 across and 4 down.

When a user clicks any logo, the logo is pushed into the grid and drops out of site. Everything runs pretty smoothly until one clicks the 5th logo. You can try it here:

[logo hider](http://warcadia.com/site/inxex.html)

Any ideas on how to correct the jump in logos when you click the 5th one?

Here's my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('.imageShowing').click(function() {

        if ($(':animated').length) {
        return false;
                    }
  $(this).animate({
    zIndex: '1',
    height: '100',
    width: '140',
    marginTop: '14px',
    marginLeft: '20px',
    marginRight: '20px',
    marginBottom: '14px',
  }, 100, function() {


    $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:90,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })

    $(this).animate({
    zIndex: '1',
    top: '480',
    opacity: '0'
  }, 1000, function() {  
  $(this).hide("fast");  
    // Animation complete.
  });
  });
});

}); //end document.ready
```

My CSS:

```
#wrapper { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; height: 1000px; position: relative;}
#grid {width: 935px; height: 531px; margin: 0 auto; background: url(images/grid.png) no-repeat center; padding:39px 4px 39px 11px; position: relative; z-index: 5;}
#logoWrapper {position: absolute; top: 38px; left: 36px }
#logoWrapper img { float: left; padding: 0 7px 6px 0; margin:0; position: relative; z-index: 6;}

#bottom { height: 500px; width: 950px; background: #fff; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; z-index: 10;}
```

The HTML is pretty straightforward. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what browser are you using? i m testing this in chrome 18.0.1025.152 m and it works.

Comment: for me it's working same for all, what browser are u using?

Comment: It works, yes. The issue is when you click the one in the top right corner, all the logos jump down for a split second.

Comment: And yes @idrumgood, that's exactly the problem. Click the last logo in any row and you get jumping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making that an unordered list, both because it will make what you want to do easier and for semantic purposes.

Then, you can position your `<li>`s relatively and the images inside them absolutely. That way animating the images won't disrupt the layout of the grid. Just hide the `<li>` at the end instead of just the image.

Comment: hmm i'll give this a try and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I did it and I took out the float and the stopping of the animation. Looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

in my chrome everything work well, but in IE 7 not working at all, in your first animate

```
$(this).animate({
    zIndex: '1',
    height: '100',
    width: '140',
    marginTop: '14px',
    marginLeft: '20px',
    marginRight: '20px',
    marginBottom: '14px',
  }
```

delete the last ',' behind marginBottom, some browser may expect another parameter.